# Logging in other Facebook users from a standalone app

Tags: facebook

I have a kiosk-like device that I'd like to integrate with Facebook. Essentially, I'd like to allow a user to log into their Facebook account, give permission to my app, which will post a text/picture/video to their wall.

Is this possible?
What API/toolkits do you recommend?

Thanks
Kane

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook Graph API. Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
:)

Comment: These are all HTTP calls, so I would need to simulate a web browser's behavior.
I was wondering if a standalone app (written in java or C#) could invoke some sort of library to log into Facebook.